# activerecord exists subquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following two models:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

I want to query clients with orders specified in a list (order_1, order_2), **at the same time, the client's all orders are needed**. I can do this by SQL below:

```
SELECT *
FROM CLIENTS C
JOIN ORDERS O
ON C.ID = O.CLIENT_ID
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT *
  FROM CLIENTS C1
  JOIN ORDERS O1
  ON C1.ID = O1.CLIENT_ID
  WHERE O1.ID IN ('order_1', 'order_2')
  AND C1.ID = C.ID
  );
```

Is there any way to do this in rails way? The following code would give the satisfied clients, but client.orders returns only the specified orders.

```
clients.includes(:orders).where(orders: { id: ['order_1', 'order_2'] })
```

I don't know how to get all information in one query.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years later, but here's how to do it (based on [this blog post](http://codesnik.github.io/rails/2015/09/03/activerecord-and-exists-subqueries.html)).

```
Order.where(client_id:
  Client.joins(:orders)
    .where(orders: {id: ['order_1', 'order_2']})
    .select(:id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A gem that exists to do that: [activerecord_where_assoc](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc) (I'm the author)

With it, you can do what you want this way:

```
clients.includes(:orders).where_assoc_exists(:orders, id: ['order_1', 'order_2'])
```

Doing it without a gem makes it easy to do mistakes or have annoying side effects, such as the one you mentionned of not having every records. Here is a whole document about [the problems](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc/blob/master/ALTERNATIVES_PROBLEMS.md).

Read more in the [documentation](https://maxlap.github.io/activerecord_where_assoc/ActiveRecordWhereAssoc/RelationReturningMethods.html). Here is an [introduction](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md) and [examples](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md).